# .htaccess config for www to non-www in Symfony2 app on Openshift

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, openshift, paas

I have a Symfony app deployed on openshift (it could be any PAAS server)

My domain uses CNAME flattening pointing like this:

```
example.com -> example-user.rhcloud.com
www -> example.com
```

My app in Openshift have these aliases:

```
example-user.rhcloud.com
example.com
www.example.com
```

My .htacces is the original from Symfony2 located in /web

DirectoryIndex app.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Everything works fine but I want to point all requests from www.example.com pointing to example.com

I tried adding these lines to my .htacces:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but when I try opening www.example.com my browser says there is a redirect loop. (example.com keeps working well)

How can I change the .htaccess file in order to point all www access pointing to the non-www domain?

Comment: I have the same issue with my site. The configuration you've published used to work, but no anymore. Seems that there is some OpenShift "filter" that works over the Apache response and changes the "Location" header of the response to point to the same domain as the originating request was targeted to... Anyone from openshift has any comments?

Comment: @triforce try to redirect from the domain administration instead of the .htaccess, this is the only way I make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution that works very well.

So I didn't have to change anything in the .htaccess file and put a redirect direct from the DNS manager which mine is cloudfare as it uses CNAME flattening.

1. I have two aliases for my app (example-user.rhcloud.com):

   - example.com
   - www.example.com
2. My domain is from godaddy, but with DNS to Cloudfare
3. In Cloudfare I added my site, and in `DNS Settings` I put two records:

   - CNAME - example.com - is an alias of example-user.rhcloud.com - TTL Automatic
   - CNAME - www - is an alias of example.com
4. Then I saved changes and opened `Page Rules` of the same site
5. I created a new page rule as follows:

   - URL pattern: www.example.com
   - Forwarding ON
   - Destination URL: http://example.com
   - Forwarding Type: 302

And that's it, now the main www route point to the one without www

Answer (score 0):

Not completely related, but if your site is dependent on traffic from search engines, it is good SEO practice to use a 301 redirect when the redirect is permanent. Read more about it here [on MOZ.com](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)